# How to print array inside array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, push

The task is to create the following array of arrays in JavaScript:

```
[
    ["HTML", 4],
    ["CSS", 3],
    ["JavaScript", 10],
    ["React", 5],
    ["Redux", 5],
    ["Node", 4],
    ["MongoDB", 7]
]
```

It actually printing output but not inside the bracket. Please help.

```
for(let i = 0; i < webTechs.length; i++){
    arr.push(webTechs[i], webTechs[i].length)
}
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Maybe `arr.push([webTechs[i], webTechs[i].length])`?

Answer (score 0):

As what you're expecting is an array of arrays, you need to push the elements as arrays themselves:

```js
    for(let i = 0; i < webTechs.length; i++){
        arr.push([webTechs[i], webTechs[i].length]) //Notice the [] to push them as array into 'arr'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]    arr.push([webTechs[i], webTechs[i].length])
this is what you are looking for i guess.

**EXPLANATION**

- arr.push("a","apple") ==> ["a","apple"]

**BUT**

- arr.push(["a","apple"]) ==> [["a","apple"]]

**USING JSON.stringify**
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I tried the way you are suggesting before but it is not working.

Comment: still youre getting the same output? i have updated the answer with proof. please try in a online editor for fresh testing.do letme know if it helped. im really puzzled now.

Comment: i added other pic again but this time with json stringify to suit your needs. see this. again. and plz let me know if it solved.

Comment: Yes, I tried and it is working. Thank you so much for your help!